# No HTTP response detected - Google Analytics on Wix

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, velo

I am using Wix and Google analytics. I have implemented GA using wix tools and marketting integration. I have also used custom trackevents to send data to GA. But the bounce rate is not correct.

Also i am getting this error

No HTTP response detected

Can anyone help me in this regard.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Google Analytics being implemented into my Wix site as a marketing integration. The tag works fine on my home page, but I get the "No HTTP response detected" error when I navigate to any new pages I create on the site.

I emailed with Wix SEO & Marketing and QA specialists for a week, and they report that their technical team has resolved the issue with the Google Analytics tag in tag assistant. They did not provide any details on the fix.

Checking Tag Assistant on my website now, it appears that the issue has been resolved and the tag is loading correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your response.